# PKCS#7 signed data structure in signed PDF document

Tags: hash, digital-signature, pdf

Is it mandatory to include PKCS#7 data (OID 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1) octet string into the sequence of PKCS#7 signed data?

I mean if you want to sign PDF, you are basically adding PKCS#7 container inside the document. And if the PCKS#7 signed data contains the whole data that was signed, that doubles the lenght of the signed PDF document.

If this is not mandatory, is there any way how to remove the octet string from OID 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1? Or is PKCS#7 signed data integrity protected so no one is able to just remove this octet string?

Comment: Apparent copy of http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24705/pkcs7-signed-data-structure-in-signed-pdf-document already answered.